# AFNetworking: How to access localized description from instance of NSError in AFHTTPRequestOperation

Tags: ios, afnetworking, nserror

I am facing weird problems with (NSError*)error object from AFHTTPRequestOperation.
I am using following method to simply access the userInfo but it's returning nil.

```
NSDictionary *infoDict = [error userInfo]; // assigning nil
```

However, while debugging I can see the error object with userInfo dictionary. Moreover I am accessing the status code as it should be.

```
code = [[[error userInfo] objectForKey:AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey] statusCode];
```

Edit 1: